# Evaluate $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{(1+x^{2})^{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Evaluate Let $f_{n}(x) = \frac{x^{2}}{(1+x^{2})^{n}}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Evaluate  the sum $$S(x) =  \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)$$.

I'm really at a lost of how to approach this. It isn't asking me to show convergence and if that was the case I have no idea to what it converges to. If I did know what it converges to then perhaps I could deduce what the sum would be. This question is in a chapter about applying the M-Test for series of functions and uniform convergence. What would be some ways to evaluate this?

Comment: its a geometric series, also your notation for the sequence is quite confusing, you probably mean $\sum_{n=0}^N x^2/(1+x^2)^n=f_N(x)$

Comment: I deduced something like that when I was playing around with it, but how can I state that properly? I has asked a question earlier about this, but I think it comes back down to me not feeling comfortable with the idea that $x$ is fixed.

Comment: @qbert there shouldn't have even been a sum in my defining of the function.....hunger made me write it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\neq0$, then, since$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(1+x^2)^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{1+x^2}\right)^n=\frac1{1-\frac1{1+x^2}}=\frac{1+x^2}{x^2},$$we have$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}=1+x^2.$$If $x=0$, then the sum is $0$, of course.

Comment: I can pull out the $x^2$ because $x$ is fixed......that's right....ugh...

Comment: You may want to consider the case $x=0$ separately.

Comment: @SangchulLee I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I should've asked this in my question, but does this converge uniformly? I don't think it does because: $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{(1+x^{2})^{n}} \leq x^{2} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{x^{2}})^n \leq \epsilon$ and since the behavior is still dependent on an $x$ it fails to be uniformly convergent.

Comment: The convergence is not uniform, since, if it was, and since it's a sum of continuous function, the sum would be continuous too. But it is not.

Comment: did you mean the sum would be uniformly continuous vs just continuous?

Comment: No. I am just saying that, if the convergence was uniform, then the sum would be continuous.

Comment: I don't fully follow. The sum of the functions would be a continuous function?....$(1+x^2)$ is not a continuous function?

Comment: The sum is the function$$\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb R&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}1+x^2&\text{ if }x\neq0\\0&\text{ if }x=0,\end{cases}\end{array}$$which is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: Ahhhh....Ok......I did state that we were looking over all of $\mathbb{R}$. I really need to get into the habit of remembering the set I am working over and those implications.  Thank you again for your help